# If an attack of opportunity is provoked by an enemy using a ranged weapon while in a threatened square, what order do the attacks happen in?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack, ranged-attack

Character A is using a ranged weapon while he is within the threatened area of character B. For that reason, character B can make an attack of opportunity against character A.

Regarding the order of the attacks:

- The attack of opportunity of character B comes before the ranged
  attack of character A, right?
- If the attack of opportunity by character B causes enough damage to
  kill character A, then character A cannot make the ranged attack
  anymore, can he?

Am I correctly understanding the rules?

Comment: And with that out of the way: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 3):

### You are correct

From the [Attacks of Opportunity](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity) rule in the Combat chapter of the *Core Rulebook*:

> An attack of opportunity “interrupts” the normal flow of actions in the round. If an attack of opportunity is provoked, immediately resolve the attack of opportunity, then continue with the next character’s turn (or complete the current turn, if the attack of opportunity was provoked in the midst of a character’s turn).

So the sequence would be, character B announces his action. Character A interrupts, and makes the AoO. If character B is still able to after resolving the attack, he can continue with his turn. As another example, character A might choose to use the Sunder maneuver as his AoO. If he does, he might destroy B's bow, rendering him unable to shoot, but still able to complete his turn.

In normal play, and depending on the terrain and situation, a character with a ranged attack who is threatened by another would normally just step back out of reach, and then shoot without provoking an AoO. Obviously, there are a myriad of reasons why this might not be practical or possible.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Doesn't look super-relevant overall to me.